# How to use microSD SDIO device

Tags: device, sd-card, uart

I am trying to communicate with a microSD SDIO device on a Galaxy Note 2 running Android 4.1.2.  I am told that SDIO support is built into this version of the OS.  I expected the SDIO device to be mounted in /dev/tty*** somewhere, but the list of devices does not change whether or not I have the card insterted.  How do I find out if and where the device was mounted?  Once I find it, can I use it like a regular UART device?